# Questions about cryptography implementations

Tags: united-states, united-kingdom, cryptography

I would like to know if implementing a hash function (such as MD5, SHA1 or SHA256) is legal.

- Is it legal in the UK to implement a hash function and release it? (I know there's Regulation of Investigatory Powers Act but can it be released?)
- In the US, do you just have to comply with exportation requirements or get your implementation licensed?

I am planning make a software but don't want to get involved with legal stuff.

Comment: *"I am planning make a software but don't want to get involved with legal stuff."* Then cryptography and protection of data is probably not the field you want to be developing for.

Comment: @RonBeyer Virtually all modern software will implement some forms of cryptography, even if only to generate random numbers or verify a license.

Comment: @forest Yes, of course, but the OP's post makes it sound like they are creating a cryptography *system*, not just something that uses it. This is an entirely different ball-game as you may realize. If you create what you believe is a cryptographically secure hash function which later is found to be flawed and exposes data (not just in your system, but others), it can open you up to repercussions.

Comment: @RonBeyer Implementing a hash function is not the same as creating a new cryptographic algorithm.

Answer (score 2):

It is legal in the UK. In theory the government could demand that you insert a backdoor, but it isn't clear how it would work if you didn't have the technical ability to do it and what the liability would be when it was inevitably abused.